# Getting Exception while mocking Java types, Namespaces

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, powermock

Getting java.lang.IllegalAccessError while mocking

my Class constructor looks like.

```
public Acct(java.lang.Class _javaType,
    javax.xml.namespace.Qname _xmlType,
    com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.description.TypeDesc _typeDesc){
super(_javaType,_xmlType,_typeDesc);
}
```

i tried mocking like this.

```
public class AcctTest extends PowerMockito{
@Test
public void testMethod(){
        java.lang.Class jType = PowerMock.mock(java.lang.Class.class);
    javax.xml.namespace.Qname xml = PowerMock.mock(javax.xml.namespace.Qname.class);
    com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.description.TypeDesc Desc = PowerMock.mock(com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.description.TypeDesc.class);
//Object creation to access constructor
}
}
```

Exception:
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: java.lang.Class
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

Looks like it is not able to access predefined java types. thanks
can someone please guide, how to mock such objects?

Comment: It's unclear to me what mocking `Class` would even mean. What would you expect the various calls on it to do? Do you really want to depend on exactly what reflection calls are made on the argument? Is there really no *actual* class you could use? (I've personally used mocking less and less over time, preferring other test doubles. It's certainly easy to overuse mocking, and I believe that's what's happening here.)

Answer (score 1):

Just avoid mocking `Class`.

```
 java.lang.Class jType = java.lang.Class.class;
```

This would be enough.

Comment: in order to invoke constructor of Acct class, first  need to mock all parameters (types, namespaces etc.) then i can create object.

Comment: sorry if i'm missing something here, but..how is Acct created (normally, not in mockito)? I mean, what's the first argument?

Comment: I mean, isn't it an specific Class? Passing `Class'` class is something unusual *and also hard to pronounce*. `Class` is a system class, and doesn't allow creating a new instance (only the jvm has that right)